# Duvida com Insert e Select

Tags: mysql

Sou novo por aqui e eu estou com uma dúvida em banco de dados que eu estou travado desde ontem, tentei resolver e nada, segue o exercício a seguir:

**Com a Tabela de Clientes (id_cliente, nm_cliente, nu_documento, dt_nascimento, etc), a Tabela de Transações (id_cliente, dt_transacao, vl_transacao, id_loja, etc) e a Tabela de Lojas (id_loja, nm_loja, etc), escreva uma Query para consultar os totais de gastos de cada cliente nesse mês. Escreva outra Query para consultar o faturamento total por loja no
mês passado.**

A minha maior dificuldade está nas Query's, o que eu fiz até agora:

```
create table Clientes(
id_cliente integer(5) auto_increment,
nm_cliente char(10) not null,
nu_documento integer(11) not null,
dt_nascimento date not null,
constraint id_cliente_pk primary key (id_cliente));

create table Lojas(
id_lojas integer(5) auto_increment,
nm_loja char(10) not null,
constraint id_lojas_pk primary key (id_lojas));

create table Transacoes(
id_cliente_transacoes integer(5),
nm_cliente_transacoes char(10),
id_lojas_transacoes integer(5),
nm_loja_transacoes char(10),
dt_transacao date not null,
gasto_cliente integer(6.2) not null,
faturamento_total integer(6.2) not null,
constraint faturamento_total_pk primary key (faturamento_total),
constraint id_cliente_transacoes_fk foreign key (id_cliente_transacoes) references Clientes(id_cliente),
constraint id_lojas_transacoes_fk foreign key (id_lojas_transacoes) references Lojas(id_lojas));

insert into Clientes(nm_cliente, nu_documento, dt_nascimento) 
values ('Pedro', 238412, DATE '1982-04-02');
insert into Clientes(nm_cliente, nu_documento, dt_nascimento) 
values ('Vinicius', 214832, DATE '1999-01-09');

insert into Lojas(nm_loja) values ('Anapalu');
insert into Lojas(nm_loja) values ('Doceria SP');

insert into Transacoes(dt_transacao, gasto_cliente, faturamento_total)
values (DATE '2018-08-20', 1450.19, 2381.93);
insert into Transacoes(dt_transacao, gasto_cliente, faturamento_total) 
values (DATE '2018-07-17', 1094.33, 1928.92);

select nm_cliente, gasto_cliente from Clientes, Transacoes;
select nm_loja, faturamento_total, dt_transacao from Lojas, Transacoes order by dt_transacao;
```

Se alguém souber fazer essa parte das Query's eu agradeço muito!

Answer (score 0):

Totais de gastos de cada cliente no mês:

```
Select Clientes.nm_cliente, Sum(Transacoes.gasto_cliente) as gastos_mensal from Transacoes 
inner join Clientes on Transacoes.id_cliente_transacoes = Clientes.id_cliente 
group by Month(Transacoes.dt_transacao);
```

Faturamento da Loja:

```
Select Lojas.nm_loja, Sum(Transacoes.faturamento_total) as faturamento_lojas from
Lojas inner join Transacoes on Lojas.id_lojas = Transacoes.id_lojas_transacoes 
gorup by Month(Transacoes.dt_transacao) where 
Month(Transacoes.dt_transacao) = Month('ano/mes/dia') 
AND Year(Transacoes.dt_transacao) = Year('ano/mes/dia')
```